# lightgbm crashes R on MAC

Tags: r, macos, installation, lightgbm

I installed lightgbm for R several times:
Operating System: Mac OS Mojave 10.14.5
CPU/GPU model: Mac Book Pro Intel 2.9 and Imac 3.2
R version:3.6.0
LightGBM version or commit hash:2.2.4

same on another Mac running same configuration except R: 3.5.3

I used the following code for installation from shell:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
cd LightGBM
Rscript build_r.R
```

After installation loading of the library is possible.
Following code works:

```
data(agaricus.train, package='lightgbm')
 train <- agaricus.train
 dtrain <- lgb.Dataset(train$data, label=train$label)
params <- list(objective="regression", metric="l2")
```

When I start training of the model:

```
model <- lgb.cv(params, dtrain, 10, nfold=5, min_data=1, learning_rate=1, early_stopping_rounds=10)
```

R crashes: Fatal error, R aborted, start new session.

I am working on that problem since 5 days and couldn't
find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

After some more days...
seemed to be an issue with openmp from clang compiler.
The build_r.R script uses clang by default.
Finally I changed compiler by executing:

```
export CXX=g++-9 CC=gcc-9
```

then executing the script. Installed and test worked.